# org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException-Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

I've updated my installed softwares in eclipse.After updating the softwares,I'm  facing error while running ruta script.The new update is Apache Uima java sdk 3.0.0 alpha version.Whether its causing the error.

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: The JCas cannot be initialized.  The following errors occurred: 
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.EvalAnnotation", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/EvalAnnotation.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.FalseNegative", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/FalseNegative.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.FalsePositive", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/FalsePositive.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.TruePositive", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/TruePositive.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.ProfiledAnnotation", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/ProfiledAnnotation.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugRuleElementMatch", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugRuleElementMatch.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugRuleMatch", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugRuleMatch.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugFailedRuleMatch", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugFailedRuleMatch.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugMatchedRuleMatch", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugMatchedRuleMatch.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugScriptApply", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugScriptApply.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugRuleApply", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugRuleApply.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugBlockApply", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/DebugBlockApply.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.RutaAnnotation", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/RutaAnnotation.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.RutaBasic", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/RutaBasic.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.RutaColoring", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/RutaColoring.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.RutaFrame", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/RutaFrame.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).
JCas Class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.html.DIV", loaded from "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/531/0/.cp/ruta-core-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/uima/ruta/type/html/DIV.class", is missing required constructor; likely cause is wrong version (UIMA version 3 or later JCas required).

at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSClassRegistry.reportErrors(FSClassRegistry.java:776)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSClassRegistry.loadAtTypeSystemCommitTime(FSClassRegistry.java:305)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.FSClassRegistry.getGeneratorsForClassLoader(FSClassRegistry.java:806)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.TypeSystemImpl.getGeneratorsForClassLoader(TypeSystemImpl.java:2597)
at org.apache.uima.cas.impl.CASImpl.commitTypeSystem(CASImpl.java:1434)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasCreationUtils.doCreateCas(CasCreationUtils.java:613)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasCreationUtils.createCas(CasCreationUtils.java:362)
at org.apache.uima.util.CasCreationUtils.createCas(CasCreationUtils.java:660)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.newCAS(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:231)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:156)
```

Answer (score 1):

Presently, there is no Ruta version that is compatible with UIMA v3 alpha. You should try reverting your Eclipse to the status before installing the UIMA v3 alpha plugins via *Help -> Installation Details -> Installation History*. Select the status from before you installed v3-alpha and click *revert*.

Comment: I did the installation process for the first time in that machine.How can I revert to 2.9.0

Comment: You can uninstall 3.0.0-alpha and then install 2.9.0